# Safe area even though I've specified FULL SCREEN

Tags: xcode, uiscrollview, safearealayoutguide

I have turned on full screen and turned off and hidden the top bar. My scroll view keeps resetting to put safe area I want safe area gone. Does any one have any clue of how to remove safe area completely? I want a full screen layout.

Safe area even though I've specified FULL SCREEN:

[image: Safe area even though I've specified FULL SCREEN]

-44 off?:

[image: -44 off?]

Layout does not match what's in Xcode:

[image: Layout does not match what's in Xcode]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select your view controller
Uncheck 'Adjust Scroll View Insets'

is the answer